# Read only one Record from the XML file and display it on listbox in WPF

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml, listbox

I have an Xml file and it has some Elements, I want to display only one on the Listbox and the listbox should be updated when new Records are added. The updating should be dynamic. I tried binding but it did not help.

Here is my Xml file

```
<empList>
<Information>
  <Name>Jack</Name>
  <Destination>AA</Destination>
  <EmployeeID>AA</EmployeeID>
</Information>
<Information>
  <Name>David</Name>
  <Destination>BB</Destination>
  <EmployeeID>BB</EmployeeID>
</Information>
<Information>
  <Name>Adam</Name>
  <Destination>wdwad</Destination>
  <EmployeeID>dwad</EmployeeID>
</Information></empList>
```

This is the class file

```
public class Information
{

     public string Name{ get; set; }

     public string Destination{ get; set; }

     public string EmployeeID{ get; set; }

    }
```

This is the Collection class file

```
public class Collection
{

    public List<Information> empList = new List<Information>();
}
```

This is the .cs file

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Collection));
            FileStream read = new FileStream("data.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
            Collection coll = (Collection)xs.Deserialize(read);
            listBox1.ItemsSource = coll.empList;


    }
```

This is the XAML file

```
 <ListBox Height="251" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="334,22,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="170" 
DataContext="{Binding {StaticResource Data}, XPath=empList/Information}"
ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Information/@Name}" />
```

Now i want to display only name on the listbox and the listbox should be automatically updated when new records are added. When i execute the abov mentioned code, i get an exception in the xaml file like "Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension"

Answer (score 1):

You can bind property in WPF and XML file is collection of Information so you need to add Collection tag at start 
Try This:

XAML:

```
<Grid >
        <ListBox Height="251" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="334,22,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="170" 
        DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
</Grid>
```

Collection:

```
public class Collection 
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Information> empList { get; set; }

        public Collection()
        {
            empList = new ObservableCollection<Information>();
        }
    }
```

XML Deserialize:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Collection));
            FileStream read = new FileStream("data.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
            Collection coll = (Collection)xs.Deserialize(read);
            listBox1.ItemsSource = coll.empList;
        }
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Collection xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <empList>
    <Information>
      <Name>Jack</Name>
      <Destination>AA</Destination>
      <EmployeeID>AA</EmployeeID>
    </Information>
    <Information>
      <Name>David</Name>
      <Destination>BB</Destination>
      <EmployeeID>BB</EmployeeID>
    </Information>
    <Information>
      <Name>Adam</Name>
      <Destination>wdwad</Destination>
      <EmployeeID>dwad</EmployeeID>
    </Information>
  </empList>
</Collection>
```